# Get branch divergence information on arbitrary refs in git

Tags: git

I'm trying to create some statistics on potentially abandoned branches in our project.

For that I would love to compare each branch with the main branch and print how many commits it is ahead/behind main. - What is the correct command to get this kind of information?

A bad workaround is creating a temporary local branch, setting main as upstream and have a look at `git branch -vv`, which will show something like: `tmp 82382e7 [origin/main: ahead 2, behind 10]`.

Is there a single command to get the "ahead 2, behind 10" without the need of a temporary local branch?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it myself:

```
git rev-list --left-right --count ref1...ref2
```